# Im trying to perform a segue but cant grab the selected cell info with an IBaction and cellForRowAt is not registering

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, ibaction

I'm trying to perform a segue and want to use the text of the selected cell to control what information is displayed on the new screen. I can use the IBaction to perform the segue but as yet can't figure out how to grab the cell info. So I then tried using
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) and didselectrowat but neither are working. I have tried removing the IBaction and deleting the button which gets rid of the Invalid argument NSexception fault but when I click on the cell absolutely nothing.
Ive included my code and in its current form the segue does happen albeit with no info displayed . If I delete the IBaction line and remove the button from the storyboard then nothing. Please point me in the right direction.

```
    //    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    @IBAction func segueToDriverRDWList(_ sender: UIButton) {

        print("SEGUE")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotodriverRDWlist", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! DriverRDWViewController
    
//        destinationVC.selectedDriver = driverNameArray[indexPath.row]
//        print(driverNameArray[indexPath.row])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you haven't confirmed datasource and delegate method of UItableview,  that's why didselect method were not working. Please refer this for more details
[https://shrikar.com/uitableview-delegate-and-datasource-in-swift/#:~:text=Create%20a%20new%20file%20called%20MainViewController.,the%20UITableViewDataSource%20and%20UITableViewDelegate%20Protocol.&text=numberOfRowsInSection%20will%20tell%20how%20many,tableview%20for%20that%20particular%20section](https://shrikar.com/uitableview-delegate-and-datasource-in-swift/#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20new%20file%20called%20MainViewController.,the%20UITableViewDataSource%20and%20UITableViewDelegate%20Protocol.&text=numberOfRowsInSection%20will%20tell%20how%20many,tableview%20for%20that%20particular%20section).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an @IBAction, just use the didSelectRowAt, and your class must conform to the UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource protocols (dataSource and delegate must be set as self as well) :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "gotodriverRDWlist" {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! DriverRDWViewController
    //Pass your data here
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotodriverRDWlist", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes that did it thank you. I did try upvoting it but because of my newness it won't let me.